# How do I add a Nexus resolver after local repository, but before the default repositories?

Tags: sbt

We have an internal Nexus repository that we use to publish artifacts to and also to cache external dependencies (from Maven Central, Typesafe, etc.)

I want to add the repository as a resolver in my SBT build, under the following restrictions:

1. The settings need to be part of the build declaration (either .sbt or .scala, but not in the "global" sbt settings
2. If a dependency exists in the local repository, it should be taken from there. I don't want to have to access the network to get all the dependencies for every build.
3. If a dependency doesn't exist locally, sbt should first try to get it from the Nexus repository before trying the external repositories.

I saw several similar questions here, but didn't find any solution that does exactly this. Specifically, the code I currently have is:

```
externalResolvers ~= { rs => nexusResolver +: rs }
```

But when I `show externalResolvers` the Nexus repo appears *before* the local one.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've come up with the following solution:

```
externalResolvers ~= { rs =>
  val grouped = rs.groupBy(_.isInstanceOf[FileRepository])
  val fileRepos = grouped(true)
  val remoteRepos = grouped(false)
  fileRepos ++ (nexusResolver +: remoteRepos)
}
```

It works, but is kinda dirty... If anyone has a "cleaner" solution, I'd love to hear it.